# Help finding critical numbers.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the critical numbers of the function:

$$f(x)=x^\frac{4}{5}(x-4)^2$$

Help would be so greatly appreciated :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1)$ find $f'(x)$:

- Use the product rule to find $f'(x)$,
- or else expand $f(x)$: $$f(x) = x^{4/5}(x^2 - 8 x + 16) = x^{14/5} -
     x^{9/5} + 16x^{4/5}$$ and find $f'(x)$.

$(2)$ Then set $f'(x) = 0$ and solve for x.

$(3)$ Check for values for which $f(x)$ is not defined (there are none).

$(4)$ Check for values for which $f'(x)$ is not defined. There is one such value $x'$. Examine what happens as you take the limit as $x \to x'$ from both the right and from the left of $x'$.

**ADDED:**

As per comments below, your derivative is correct. Expressing it with a common denominator and setting equal to zero gives us:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{10x(x-4) + 4(x-4)^2}{5x^{1/5}}$$

So we need to check what happens at $$x = 0$$ as described above, when $f'(x)$ is undefined.

Then, the derivative will be zero (with two "zeros") when 
$$10x(x-4) + 4(x-4)^2 = 0$$

Factoring and simplifying gives us $$2(x-4)(5x + 4x - 16) = 2(x-4)(9x-16) = 0$$

which is has roots (values at which $f'(x) = 0$) when $$x = 4, \quad x = \dfrac{16}{9}$$

Comment: I've used the chain rule and gotten to: $$F'(x)=x^\frac{4}{5}2(x-4)+(x-4)^2\frac{4}{5}x^\frac{-1}{5}$$ What would I do after that? Is my derivative correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is. Now try to find the common denominator and express as a fraction. Denominator = $5x^{1/5}$. The derivative will not be defined at $x = 0$. But otherwise, critical values will occur when the $f'(x) = 0$: when the numerator is equal to zero.

Comment: ok this is where I get stuck, when I set the numerator equal to zero: $$10x(x-4)+4x^\frac{1}{5}(x-4)^2=0$$ how would I solve that equation...? Would you move $10x(x-4)$ to one side and have $$10x(x-4)=4x^\frac{1}{5}(x-4)^2$$

Comment: You want to factor the numerator to find roots.